# How does HashSet not allow duplicates?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I was going through the `add` method of `HashSet`. It is mentioned that

> If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false.

But the `add` method is internally saving the values in `HashMap`

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

The `put` method of `HashMap` states that

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.

**So if the `put` method of `HashMap` replaces the old value, how the `HashSet` `add` method leaves the set unchanged in case of duplicate elements?**

Comment: Kudos for looking up the source code for `HashSet.add`.  Did you look up the source for `HashMap.put`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`PRESENT` is just a dummy value -- the set doesn't really care what it is. What the set *does* care about is the map's *keys*. So the logic goes like this:

```
Set.add(a):
  map.put(a, PRESENT) // so far, this is just what you said
    the key "a" is in the map, so...
      keep the "a" key, but map its value to the PRESENT we just passed in
      also, return the old value (which we'll call OLD)
  look at the return value: it's OLD, != null. So return false.
```

Now, the fact that `OLD == PRESENT` doesn't matter -- and note that `Map.put` doesn't change the key, just the value mapped to that key. Since the map's *keys* are what the `Set` really cares about, the `Set` is unchanged.

In fact, there *has* been some change to the underlying structures of the `Set` -- it replaced a mapping of `(a, OLD)` with `(a, PRESENT)`. But that's not observable from outside the `Set`'s implementation. (And as it happens, that change isn't even a real change, since `OLD == PRESENT`).

Answer (score 8):

The answer that you may be looking comes down to the fact that the backing hashmap maps the elements of the set to the value `PRESENT` which is defined in [HashSet.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) as follows:

```
private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();
```

In the source code for `HashMap.put` we have:

```
  386     public V put(K key, V value) {
  387         if (key == null)
  388             return putForNullKey(value);
  389         int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
  390         int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
  391         for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
  392             Object k;
  393             if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
  394                 V oldValue = e.value;
  395                 e.value = value;
  396                 e.recordAccess(this);
  397                 return oldValue;
  398             }
  399         }
  400 
  401         modCount++;
  402         addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
  403         return null;
  404     }
```

Because the key in question already exists, we will take the early return on line 397.  But you might think a change is being made to the map on line 395, in which it appears that we are changing the value of a map entry.  However, the value of `value` is `PRESENT`.  But because `PRESENT` is static and final, so there is only one such instance; and so the assignment `e.value = value` actually doesn't change the map, and therefore the set, at all!

> **Update**:
>
> Once a `HashSet` is initialized.
>      - All the items in it are stored as keys in a `HashMap`
>      - All the values that `HashMap` have ONLY ONE object that is `PRESENT` which is a static field in `HashSet`

Comment: @RayToal, How you have copied the code along with line numbers??

Comment: Copied from [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java)

Answer (score 5):

As you can see the `HashSet.add` method adds the element to the `HashMap.put` as a key not as a value. Value is replaced in the `HashMap` not the key.

Comment: Yes.  All the values in the map are the same (PRESENT).  The HashSet is using the inner map and its KEY portion to store the elements of the Set

Answer (score 3):

See [`HashMap#put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29):

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If
>   the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is
>   replaced.

It replaces the key with the *new* value, this way, no duplicates will be in the `HashSet`.

Comment: I got this that no duplicated will be in the `HashSet`, I wan't to know why the old duplicate value is not getting overwritten in the `HashSet`?

Comment: @Shaan, The map value may be replaced, (which is a constant static field in HashSet class and thus replaced with the same instance), and the map key is left untouched (which, in fact IS the Set collection item)

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

e is the key, So if **e** is already present `put` will not return `null`. Hence `add` will return false.

JavaDoc for `put` :

> the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key.)

Answer (score 1):

From javadocs for HashMap.put(),
"Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced."

Thus the map value will be replaced, (which is a constant static field in HashSet class, and thus the same instance is replaced), and the map key is kept untouched (which, in fact IS the Set collection item)